# R symbol in LaTeX

Tags: code, r

I am loooking for a LaTeX command similar to `\LaTeX` but for the statistic program R. Does anybody know if there exists sth?

Comment: as far as I am aware it is just written as R in text, or use the image of the logo from https://www.r-project.org/

Comment: You could take the [svg logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:R_logo.svg), convert that to pdf and use it with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: See the duplicate for the old logo, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256202/new-r-logo-with-tikz for the new logo.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74771/making-a-latex-text-r-logo-how-maintain-the-proportions

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use a `fontawesome5` icon.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\LaTeX\ and {\color{blue}\faRProject} work well together
\end{document}
```